# Using knockout to progressively load an array of video metadata

Tags: javascript, html, video, knockout.js

My page needs to display a grid of *n* video previews.  Browsers can only have ~5-6 active connections with any given domain.  To prevent the "Waiting for socket connection..." issue, I'm attempting to progressively load video metadata.

I have the following:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: videos() -->
  <video data-bind="attr: {src: mediaPath, preload: $parent.preloadCount() > $index() ? 'metadata' : 'none'}, event: {loadedmetadata: $parent.incrementPreloadCount}"></video>
 <!--/ko-->
```

Within my viewmodel:

```
    vm.preloadCount = ko.observable(4);
    vm.incrementPreloadCount = function () {
        feedVm.preloadCount(feedVm.preloadCount() + 1);
    };
```

The idea being that each time a video's metadata is loaded, the `loadedmetadata` event fires off an increment that progressively switches `none` to `metadata`.

The problem with this is that my `videos` are reevaluating with every increment, refetching the `src` each time `preloadCount` updates.

How can I prevent previously "switched" videos from being re-evaluated?  I could resort to a relatively simple JS solution here but I'd like to take advantage of knockout if I can.

Comment: The only potential issue in given markup is the expression for the `preload` attribute which automaticaly converted to `computed` by KO. But normally `computed` reevaluates only when its value actually changes. So I guess there is another issue somewhere behind. Could you create the functional example that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: @f_martinez - `preloadCount` is what's changing and triggering the reevaluation afaik

Comment: Your comparison (`$parent.preloadCount() > $index()`) should be a `computed` for each video.

Comment: @RoyJ - given that `videos` is a computed itself (filtering an original array), how would I go about adding a `computed` property to each `video` object that knows its `$index`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` supplies a second argument to its function, which is the index of the element being operated on. You can use that as a stand-in for `$index` in a computed that returns a map of your array.

Making a computed to handle the `preload` attribute value should keep your video elements from being touched except when the value of that computed changes.

```js
const vm = {
  arr: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
  preloadCount: ko.observable(0)
};

vm.videos = ko.computed(() => vm.arr.map((v, i) => ({
  v,
  i,
  preload: ko.computed(() => vm.preloadCount() > i ? 'metadata' : 'none')
})));

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(() => vm.preloadCount(1 + vm.preloadCount()), 1200);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: videos">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: i"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: v"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: preload"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```